# Xcode Pinch Zoom portrait landscape

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiscrollview, pinchzoom

I am using the following code for Pinch Zoom

```
scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];

scroll.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
scroll.delegate = self;

scroll.contentSize = _imageView.frame.size;
[scroll addGestureRecognizer:tap];

scroll.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"main_bg_PiPad"]];
[scroll addSubview:_imageView];
[scroll addSubview:_viewFrameCapture];
_viewFrameCapture.hidden=YES;
scroll.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
scroll.maximumZoomScale = 5.0;
[scroll setZoomScale:scroll.minimumZoomScale];
self.view = scroll;
```

everything is working fine for me. But the problem is when I am in Landscape mode pinch zoom is working perfectly, when I move to Portrait mode, Pinch Zoom is not working properly, when I reduce the size of the image and remove the finger, it immediately resizes to original image size, can anyone help me how to solve this problem.